# Power Query - Select Values from table b if table a is null

Tags: excel, database, merge, powerbi, powerquery

Is there a way via Power Query to merge 2 tables but take the values from Table A (If available) and if not, take the values from Table B.  I have Table A (Manually uploading data) in which I want the values if available.  If not, I want the values from Table B (Table joined to database that sometimes is not updated/accurate).

Uploading manual data allows me to correct the incorrect data from Table B.

I tried Merging tables but was getting duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, Merge TableA into TableB

Expand the desired field from TableA using the arrows atop the new column

Add column... custom column... and test the expanded field for null, and if null, take another field

```
=  if [somefield]=null then [someotherfield] else [somefield]
```

or

```
= [somefield] ?? [someotherfield]
```

If you are getting duplicate rows, then you need to be more specific what you want to do in that case. Take the first row of the matching data? Take the maximum of some column, etc?  Apply that step to the merged column with a new custom column, before expanding. For example, a custom column just taking the first row from the merged column would be

```
= Table.FirstN([MergedColumnNameBeforeExpanding],1)
```

then you could expand this new column in place of the original merged one